# JS Event Listener within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, event-listener

Hey I have the following code, which functions correctly how dealing with audio events, however this doesn't work within an iFrame:

```
var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
/* Loop through the nodelist - this is **not** an array */
for(var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++){
/* Get the item in your nodelist. This **is** an element. */
var sound = sounds.item(i);
/* Now add your event listener here - You can only add one at a 
 * time, though. So I decided to make the event a separate  
 * function and attach it multiple timers. */
function eventHandler(){
    document.title = document.title.replace('\u25B6', '')
    if (!sound.paused) {
        document.title = '\u25B6 ' + document.title.replace('\u25B6 ', '')
        return false;
    }
}
sound.addEventListener('play', eventHandler, false);
sound.addEventListener('pause', eventHandler, false);
sound.addEventListener('ended', eventHandler, false);
}
```

So I have used the following code, but this comes up with the error: "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'iframe.contentWindow.getElementsByTagName('audio')')"

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); //all iframes on page
for(var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++){
var iframe = iframes.item(i);
var sounds = iframe.contentWindow.getElementsByTagName('audio');
/* Loop through the nodelist - this is **not** an array */
for(var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++){
/* Get the item in your nodelist. This **is** an element. */
var sound = sounds.item(i);
/* Now add your event listener here - You can only add one at a 
 * time, though. So I decided to make the event a separate  
 * function and attach it multiple timers. */
function eventHandler(){
    document.title = document.title.replace('\u25B6', '')
    if (!sound.paused) {
        document.title = '\u25B6 ' + document.title.replace('\u25B6 ', '')
        return false;
    }
 }
}
    sound.addEventListener('play', eventHandler, false);
    sound.addEventListener('pause', eventHandler, false);
    sound.addEventListener('ended', eventHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: Hello again! Just my two pence, but I think you need to select the document before calling any elements getters: `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('audio');` - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I just did a little test and all you are missing is calling the `getElementsByTagName` function on the iFrames' `document`, as the `contentWindow` is the iFrames' `window` element (similar to the `window` element in your parent page).

You cannot use iFrames in code snippets here, so I can't show you an implementation, but this should work (it worked in my testing (although I tried it with loading CNN.com and counting the number of `div`s returned by `getElementByTagName`, and that worked):

```
var iframe = iframes.item(i);
iframe = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var sounds = iframe.getElementsByTagName('audio');
```

**Keep in mind** that `content-origin` restrictions apply here. If you did noit instantiate the iframe or its not on the same domain, *errors can occur*.

Comment: Hey I have tried this before, and tried it again:

I get this error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iframe.contentWindow')

To make sure I haven't missed anything i've put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GFDUhLhfUt

Comment: In your fiddle, there are no `iframe`s. Also notice that I _did not redefine_ your `iframe`, I continued on from it. `var iframe = iframes.item(i);` was correct. That gives you the `iframe` element, then `contentWindow` gives you the `window` element of the page inside the `iframe`, and then the `document` gives you the `document` inside that `window` element.